# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having an issue with min() max() and `str` and `numpy.ndarray`. I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I suspect the problem is with the `haHigh0` in the line that defines `haUpLeg0`, and I would appreciate any input as to how I could correct. I have looked through stack at some similar problems but cant seem to get a fix to translate to my problem.

**Data:**

```
Date        Time    Open    High    Low    Close    Volume  Ticker 
02/01/2015  14:30   79.52   79.73   79.52   79.71   10841   DVY 
02/01/2015  14:31   79.6999 79.6999 79.61   79.67   1426    DVY 
02/01/2015  14:32   79.69   79.7    79.69   79.7    800     DVY 
02/01/2015  14:33   79.7    79.759  79.7    79.759  1158    DVY 
02/01/2015  14:34   79.747  79.747  79.73   79.73   1125    DVY 
02/01/2015  14:35   79.73   79.73   79.71   79.71   301     DVY 
02/01/2015  14:36   79.8    79.82   79.75   79.82   7818    DVY 
02/01/2015  14:37   79.82   79.83   79.778  79.82   6985    DVY
```

**Code:**

```
mkt_data = index_data[['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]
open0 = mkt_data['Open'] #
high0 = mkt_data['High'] #
low0 = mkt_data['Low'] #
close0 = mkt_data['Close'] #
date0 = mkt_data['Date'] #
time0 = mkt_data['Time'] #
ticker0 = index_data['Ticker'] #

close1 = mkt_data['Close'].shift(1) #
open1 = mkt_data['Open'].shift(1) # 
high1 = mkt_data['High'].shift(1) #
low1 = mkt_data['Low'].shift(1) #
high2 = mkt_data['High'].shift(2) #
low2 = mkt_data['Low'].shift(2) #
close2 = mkt_data['Close'].shift(2) # 
open2 = mkt_data['Open'].shift(2) #
close3 = mkt_data['Close'].shift(3) # 
open3 = mkt_data['Open'].shift(3) #

haClose2 = (open2 + high2 + low2 + close2) / 4  #
haOpen2 = (close3 + open3) / 2  #       

haClose1 = (open1 + high1 + low1 + close1) / 4  #
haOpen1 = (haClose2 + haOpen2) / 2  #
haHigh1 = max('high1', 'haOpen1', 'haClose1') #
haLow1 = min('low1', 'haOpen0', 'haClose1') # 

haClose0 = (open0 + high0 + low0 + close0) / 4 #
haOpen0 = (haClose1 + haOpen1) / 2 #


haHigh0 = max('high0', 'haOpen0', 'haClose0') #
haLow0 = min('low0', 'haOpen0', 'haClose0')  #
haUpLeg0 = (haHigh0 - haClose0) / (close1) #
```

Comment: Is this `pandas`? Also can you post raw input data and the minimum amount of code to reproduce your error as a lot of looks superfluous

Comment: for example `max('high0', 'haOpen0', 'haClose0')` return `'high0'` a `str` and `haClose0` is a `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: Date Time Open High Low Close Volume Ticker
02/01/2015 14:30 79.52 79.73 79.52 79.71 10841 DVY
02/01/2015 14:31 79.6999 79.6999 79.61 79.67 1426 DVY
02/01/2015 14:32 79.69 79.7 79.69 79.7 800 DVY
02/01/2015 14:33 79.7 79.759 79.7 79.759 1158 DVY
02/01/2015 14:34 79.747 79.747 79.73 79.73 1125 DVY
02/01/2015 14:35 79.73 79.73 79.71 79.71 301 DVY
02/01/2015 14:36 79.8 79.82 79.75 79.82 7818 DVY
02/01/2015 14:37 79.82 79.83 79.778 79.82 6985 DVY

Comment: you can try with `max(high0, haOpen0, haClose0)` instead of `max('high0', 'haOpen0', 'haClose0')`

Comment: Ron, put that info in your question, correctly formatted ; not in a comment.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I changed to max(max(high0),max(haOpen0),max(haClose0)) which worked ... I need to figure my str from my numpy..

Comment: Hi, as a follow on to above , I am trying to store
haHigh1 = max(max(high1),max(haOpen1),max(haClose1))                      
in a dictionary.................dHaHigh1 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, haHigh1]...........  but im getting the error  
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer.........

I nave tried np.nan, but needs to be an array , any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to find the highest value out of the three--high0, haOpen0, haClose0--you could do

```
max(max(high0),max(haOpen0),max(haClose0))
```

I think you should not use quotes around the variable names.  'high0' is a string, but high0 is a pandas Series.

Comment: Hi, as a follow on to above , I am trying to store
haHigh1 = max(max(high1),max(haOpen1),max(haClose1))                      
in a dictionary.................dHaHigh1 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, haHigh1]...........  but im getting the error  
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer.........

I nave tried np.nan, but needs to be an array , any suggestions please?

Comment: Please post as a new question -- don't bury in the comments, piggybacked on an entirely different root issue, with no way to format the data readably. Also, just because someone saw the error in your first problem, doesn't mean they're the best ones to keep helping subsequent problems. Use the site like it wants to be used. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Near the bottom, it looks like you start to use variable names and strings interchangeably, eg:

```
haClose1 = (open1 + high1 + low1 + close1) / 4  #
haOpen1 = (haClose2 + haOpen2) / 2  #
haHigh1 = max('high1', 'haOpen1', 'haClose1') #
haLow1 = min('low1', 'haOpen0', 'haClose1') #
```

You probably want to keep using variables:

```
haClose1 = (open1 + high1 + low1 + close1) / 4  #
haOpen1 = (haClose2 + haOpen2) / 2  #
haHigh1 = max(high1, haOpen1, haClose1) #
haLow1 = min(low1, haOpen0, haClose1) #
```

etc.

That is to say, you're getting a TypeError because `-` (and `+` etc) is an unsupported operand type between `str` and `numpy.ndarray` -- you can't subtract one from (or add one to) the other.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I changed to max(max(high0),max(haOpen0),max(haClose0)) which worked ... I need to figure my str from my numpy.

Comment: Hi, as a follow on to above , I am trying to store
haHigh1 = max(max(high1),max(haOpen1),max(haClose1))                      
in a dictionary.................dHaHigh1 = mkt_data.ix[numRow, haHigh1]...........  but im getting the error  
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer.........

I nave tried np.nan, but needs to be an array , any suggestions please?